# Assign/Push ClaimsPrincipal to SignalR Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, signalr, signalr-hub

Ok, So this one is certainly pushing me towards the edge of the cliff... Having worked with V1 of `SignalR` with relative ease, I'm certainly struggling now.

**The Problem:** "Grabbing" `Claims` from the recently authenticated user and passing/using in a `Hub`

**The Environment**:

WebAPI Authenticating with `Basic Auth` over `SSL`. The logic for authenticating is within an attribute and works fine and has been for months, it also generates/builds Claims within `AuthenticateAsync`

In my `API Controller` I grab the claims:

```
var idenityInstance = new IdentityInstance(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
```

I have spent the weekend trying to incorporate V2 of SignalR utilizing Groups/SSL and Authentication.

I generally thought the ClaimsPrincipal would be passed over or in the same "Context".

```
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
                app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                    // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                    // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                    // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                    // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                    {
                        // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                        // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                        // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                        // EnableJSONP = true
                    };
                    // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                    // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                    // path.
                    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
                });

            }
```

Custom Authorize Attribute (Grabbed from the Docs)

```
        protected override bool UserAuthorized(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }

            var principal = user as ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (principal != null)
            {
                Claim authenticated = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Authentication);
                if (authenticated != null && authenticated.Value == "true")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Ok, Last snippet, The Hub (stripped back)**

```
        public async Task Hello()
        {
            //Temp line for testing under local SSL/Self signed
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
                += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:44357");


            IHubProxy chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("printerHub");



            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            var c = Context;
            await hubContext.Clients.All.hello("Hello");
        }
```

Again the problem is when I debug through the `Hub Method Hello();` `Context` is always `null` and ultimately does not `authenticate` due to the custom `attribute`

I'm hoping I've just missed something silly here, because it's certainly very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was a little trickier than first anticipated, now the solution may not fit "some" environments but in this case, solved the problem.

It's always bearing in mind that we are dealing with two `Contexts`...

To re-cap I have a `WebAPI` with `basic auth` over `SSL` - which is working amazingly well, now the idea was to provide a way to lock down the `Hubs` and only allow access to **authenticated** users and outside the scope of the `basic auth`. Due to `WebAPI` and `SignalR` running in two process's access to the `Hubs` can be outside the `WebAPI` pipeline.

A little code to demonstrate:

**The Hub:**

```
    [HubAuthorizationAttribute]
    [HubName("printerHub")]
    public class PrinterHub : Hub
    {
        private static IHubContext hubContext =
            GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PrinterHub>();


        private IdentityInstance _userInstanceContext;
        private User _user;
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //Custom logic to return a User object
            _userInstanceContext = new IdentityInstance(this.Context.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
            _user = _userInstanceContext.Create();
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopping)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopping);
        }
        public async Task JoinPrinterNotifications()
        {
            await hubContext.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, _user.ClientName + ":Printers");
        }
        public async Task PrintQueues(IEnumerable<QueuedPrintItem> items)
        {
            await hubContext.Clients.Group(_user.ClientName + ":Printers").notify(items);
        }
```

**The SignalR custom Auth Attribute**

```
public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, 
    IRequest request)
{

    //This should be sent in the Header - but will not work with
    //Websockets, if a custom header is required, ensure the transport type is "LongPolling" for demo purposes, QueryString was chosen. 
    var token = request.QueryString.Get("Token");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        return false;

        //Logic omitted to perform checks and the validity of a request

        if (client == null)
            return false;

        //build the claims identity
        Claim clientIdClaim = new Claim("Id", "SignalR: " + client.Id.ToString());
        Claim clientNameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "SignalR: " + client.ClientName);
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            clientIdClaim,
            clientNameClaim,
        };
        //"Basic" is required to ensure IsAuthenticated is set, amongst others.
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
        // set the authenticated user principal into environment so that it can be used in the future
        request.Environment["server.User"] = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return true;
  }
  public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
  {

    var connectionId = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.ConnectionId;
    // check the authenticated user principal from environment
    var environment = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request.Environment;
    var principal = environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (principal == null || 
        principal.Identity == null || 
        principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        return false;

        // create a new HubCallerContext instance with the principal generated from token
        // and replace the current context so that in hubs we can retrieve current user identity
        hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context = new HubCallerContext(new ServerRequest(environment), connectionId);
        return true;
}
```